# Connecting with Facebook API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[Query window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N277z.jpg)
I have problems with connecting with the Facebook API in Power BI.
Problem occurs when I try to aggregate the number of likes from a table -Count of id. Well it works perfectly with pages with a low number of likes, like a local blog and my personal page but when I try to do that (count) with a page with a lot of likes the aggregation process never finishes. Once I let it run for 20 minutes. I tried to limit the number of posts to a very low number, such as 40, and 10 but it still could not finish the aggregation.
Please help me finding a solution!

Places where I looked for the answer:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140616113222-14085524-using-power-query-to-tell-your-story-form-your-facebook-data

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a **Transform / Count Rows** step, instead of your Aggregation.